# JUnit: should I do null-checks after assertNotNull

Tags: junit

Should I do null-checks after `assertNotNull` to avoid null-pointers in test code? E.g.

```
assertNotNull(foo);
if (foo != null) {
    assertNotNull(foo.getBar());
}
```

Or just

```
assertNotNull(foo);
assertNotNull(foo.getBar());
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `assertX` methods ensure the condition is actually asserted. So, by using `assertNotNull` you ensure that something is not null.

The correct way is as you showed:

```
assertNotNull(foo);
assertNotNull(foo.getBar());
```

If you start digging deeper into the `assertNotNull` method, you will see this calls:

```
// First call
static public void assertNotNull(Object object) {
    assertNotNull(null, object);
}
// Second call
static public void assertNotNull(String message, Object object) {
    assertTrue(message, object != null);
}
// Third call
static public void assertTrue(String message, boolean condition) {
    if (!condition) {
        fail(message);
    }
}
```

Quoting the assertTrue documentation:

> Asserts that a condition is true. If it isn't it throws an AssertionError with the given message.

Conclusion, you don't have to do null checks after asserting for not null values since junit is taking care of that for you

Answer (score 3):

You are doing right with...

```
assertNotNull(foo);
assertNotNull(foo.getBar());
```

You don't need to set another condition to check the same if you previously did it.

Answer (score 0):

You even don't need to have the first null check. The test will fail with a `NullPointerException` if `foo` is null. It is a matter of taste whether to have the null check or not.